# Sequence operator and error term

Tags: c#, lambda, lambda-calculus

I am trying to express sequence operator

```
g*f = λz.(g z = error) -> error, (f o g)z
```

where

```
f o g = λz.f(g z)
```

using delegates for constructing lambda expressions in C#

```
public delegate Lambda Lambda(Lambda x);
```

The problem is I don't know how to encode error term. 
Is there any way to express it like True of False terms or Church numerals ?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to have a type, that either says "Error" or "The result is ..."?

That would be nothing else than the `Maybe`-Monad, I would encode it via a pair of boolean and actual result:

```
// you already have/know these:
Lambda lTrue = ...
Lambda lFalse = ...
Lambda not = ...
Lambda if = ...  // = Identity for usual church encoding of booleans

// "Pair" type
Lambda makePair = a => b => (f => f(a)(b));
Lambda getFst = pair => pair (a => b => a);
Lambda getSnd = pair => pair (a => b => b);

// "Error" type/monad
Lambda constError = makePair(lFalse)(null);
Lambda returnResult = result => makePair(lTrue)(result);

Lambda isError = error => not(getFst(error));
Lambda isResult = error => getFst(error);     // = getFst
Lambda getResult = error => getSnd(error);    // = getSnd

Lambda bindError = error => op => if(isResult(error))
                                      (op(getResult(error)))
                                      (constError);
```

Now given that not only your two methods `f` and `g` return an `Error` type (= either error or result) - formal `f,g :: T -> Error U` - your sequence operator looks like this (I assume it is no accident that your argument order is different from `o`-operator):

```
Lambda sequence = g => f => (z => bindError(g(z))(f))
```